# Logical Problem with the output of the function

Tags: python

This function works like a checklist. It takes a task name and date in the format `yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS`, and appends them to a list as a tuple. However, when I print them out there is a problem.

When printing the tuple it look like `("A", 2022/12/08 22:15:56)`. What I am actually seeing is something like `('A', datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 8, 22, 23, 56)`.

The second problem I have is how to retrieve the values from inside the tuple for use in the function. I don't want them to be printed like `("A",2022/12/08 22:15:56)`. I want them to be outside of the tuple parenthesis.

```
from datetime import datetime
ToDoList = []
Format_Time = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"  # formatting type for strptime function


def addNewItems():
    global ToDoList
    while True:
        name = input("Pleas enter your task's name: ")
        if checkItemExists(name) == True:
            print("Task already exists! Select the options again.")
            continue
        else:
            Task_Name = name  # storing in another variable
            break
    while True:
        date = input(
            "Please enter your task's completion date as yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS : ")
        date = datetime.strptime(date, Format_Time)
        if date < datetime.now():  # determines if the date is in the past or not
            print("Time entered is in the past! Select the options again")
            continue
        else:
            Complete_Time = date  # Storing in another variable
            print(Complete_Time)
            break
    task = (Task_Name, Complete_Time)
    ToDoList.append(task)
    ToDoList.sort(key=takeSecond)


def checkItemExists(taskName):
    global ToDoList
    for i in ToDoList:
        if taskName == i[0]:
            return True


def takeSecond(element):
    global ToDoList
    for i in ToDoList:
        if element == i[0]:
            return i[1]


def printListItems():
    global ToDoList
    for count, task in enumerate(ToDoList):
        print(count, end=".")
        print(task)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing some fundamental ideas. Running `datetime.now()` creates a `datetime` object, as you're seeing when you look at `('A', datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 8, 22, 23, 56)`

```
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.now()
>>> type(dt)
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 9, 15, 45, 2, 88861)
```

The datetime object allows you to do all kinds of cool operations and comparisons, and you just need to convert it to `str` when you're ready to show it to a human. This is handled automatically by `print` or you can cast it directly as `str` if you want to get fancier.

```
>>> dt.year # Cool thing
2022
>>>> print(dt)
2022-11-09 15:45:02.088861
>>> str(dt)
'2022-11-09 15:45:02.088861'
>>> print("The time was " + dt) # This will fail
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.datetime") to str
>>> print("The time was " + str(dt)) # This will work
The time was 2022-11-09 15:45:02.088861
```

As for the `tuple` thing, you can access the items just like you can with lists:

```
>>> mytup
('Foo', 'Bar')
>>> mytup[0]
'Foo'
>>> mytup[1]
'Bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first misunderstanding is what happens when you do this (in the REPL):

```
>>> format_time = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
>>> my_tuple = (1, datetime.strptime("1919/04/13 12:00:00", format_time))
>>> print(my_tuple)
(1, datetime.datetime(1919, 4, 13, 12, 0))
```

This prints these values *as they think of themselves*. That is why you see `datetime.datetime(..)` part of the printout. When you call `strptime()` you are converting a string `"1919/04/13 12:00:00"` type object into a datetime type object.

Notably, the way that happens is via `format_time`, which is the template that `strptime()` uses to interpret the string. When `print()` is called, it asks the datetime object for a string that represents itself. That string includes the object type (`datetime.datetime`), which is what `print()` is then showing on your screen.

The datetime object [contains some functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-datetime) to help you out:

```
print(my_tuple[1].("The time is %d, %b, %Y)")
```

For your second question:

```
>>> my_tuple = ("Hello", "World")
>>> print(my_tuple)
('Hello', 'World')
>>> h, w = my_tuple
>>> print(f"{w}, {h}")
World, Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Both problems are solved by changing your very last line to

```
print (task[0],task[1])
```

which makes the elements available for formatting. With no additions it would look like

> Fix next bug 2022-11-10 10:20:22